# iOS - why does calling an empty constructor break the program?

Tags: objective-c

I have a constructor like this:

```
-(id) init 
{
    // do something here...not sure what yet  :)
}
```

I can instantiate objects of this class just fine, but I was getting errors calling method on this class.  Why is that the case? What am I missing here? Should I have called the superclass constructor? Or is there a memory issue somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: Call the superclass's constructor?

Comment: you're not returning anything. (`id` is a return type - a pointer)

Comment: The compiler is spewing a warning that tells you what is wrong....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What am I missing here?

You are missing a call to the designated initializer of the superclass, an assignment to `self`, and a `return` statement.

Your minimal unfinished constructor should look like this:

```
-(id) init 
{
    if (self=[super init]) {
        // do something here...not sure what yet  :)
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return something, usually self, you are specifying that your method return type (id) which in objective-c can be anything, but you have to return something.

A typical init looks like this:

```
-(id) init 
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
    // do something here...not sure what yet  :)
    }
    return self;
}
```